# Confirmation of convergence proof for power sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'd just like confirmation that this is a correct proof:

> Prove that if $x > 0$ then $(x^{-n}) \to 1$.

I proved this by considering the 2 domains $x \geq 1$ and $0 < x \leq 1$. For the former case, 
$$
x \geq 1 \Longleftrightarrow x^{-n} \geq 1
$$
hence letting $a_n = x^{-n}-1$, we have
$$
x = \left(a_n + 1\right)^n \geq 1 + n\cdot a_n
$$
by Bernoulli's inequality. Using the first inequality this gives the following sandwich inequality
$$
\frac{x-1}{n}\geq a_n \geq 0.
$$
Taking the limit of the expression on the left and then using the sandwich theorem $$
\left(a_n\right) \to 0 \\
\left(a_n + 1\right)\to 1 \\
\implies \left(x^{-n}\right)\to1
$$ 
as required. This is the part I'm unsure about; if we consider
$$
x^{-n} \text{ for } x \geq 1 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{y^{-n}} \text{ for } 0 < y \leq 1
$$
then by Quotient rule

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(y^{-n} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{x^{-n}} \right)= \frac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(x^{-n}\right)} = \frac{1}{1}.
$$
Hence $\left(y^{-n}\right) \to 1$ for $0 < y \leq 1$ as required. Adding the two cases together gives the statement $\left(x^{-n}\right) \to 1$ for $x > 0$ as required.

Comment: $x\geq 1\iff x^{-n} \leq 1$ also $a_n=x^{-n} - 1$ then $x=(a_n+1)^{1/n}$

Comment: What about the case $x=2^{-1}$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah What do you mean?

Comment: @kingW3 I don't get how that helps.

Comment: @JohnMiller I'm just pointing the errors you've made in your post, I thought it could be helpful.